# How to get form answer in javascript's alert like window

Tags: php

Without using any Javascript's `alert()` function, how to force browser to show answer from PHP server in a window like this:

[image]

Comment: Without JS you don't. You're only option would be to style a popup similar to the alert box.

Comment: A javascript modal ?

Comment: javascripts `confirm` or `prompt` function maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to show such a window without JavaScript.

There are other opportunities when you don't want to use the `alert()` function.

For example the Bootstrap Framework has included quite a good JS Plugin.

**http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals**